# Let PHP WordPress function be visible for visitors

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to install a TinyMCE plugin in WordPress. This all works, but only for Administrators. I have embedded the TinyMCE text editor with the wp_editor() function, which is intended to be visible for visitors. But I don't understand how to change the code to let it be visible for everyone (also visitors of the website). The PHP code is:

```
<?php


if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
    die( "Can't load this file directly" );

class Extra_Plugins_Buttons
{
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'action_admin_init' ) );
    }

    function action_admin_init() {
        // only hook up these filters if we're in the admin panel, and the current user has permission
        // to edit posts and pages
            add_filter( 'mce_buttons_3', array( $this, 'filter_mce_button3' ) );
                        add_filter( 'mce_buttons_4', array( $this, 'filter_mce_button4' ) );

            add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', array( $this, 'filter_mce_plugin' ) );
    }

    function filter_mce_button3( $buttons ) {
        // add a separation before our button, here our button's id is "mygallery_button"
        array_push( $buttons
                        ,'jbimages'

                        );
        return $buttons;
    }

    function filter_mce_plugin( $plugins ) {
        // this plugin file will work the magic of our button
                $plugins['jbimages'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/editor/jbimages/plugin.min.js';

        return $plugins;
    }
}

$mygallery = new Extra_Plugins_Buttons();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change admin_init to init. init will work for admin as well as frontend.

In your constructor change admin_int to init or replace that code with below code with constructor.

```
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'action_admin_init' ) );
}
```